# Chazon ish translation

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, translation

Does the community know where I can find an English translation of the Chazon Ish’s masterpiece (well the Chazon ish).

Comment: Do you have some reason to think it has been translated? Most rabbinic works have not been.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by masterpiece, you mean his commentary on the Talmud, this has not been translated. His masterpiece in *emuna* however titled *Emuna u'bitachon* has been translated and is published by Judaica Press, e.g., [here](https://judaicapress.com/products/faith-and-trust-emunah-ubitachon-by-the-chazon-ish).